# in mysql adding a mysql unique contraint to a field

Tags: mysql

Initially unique contraint was not there for emp_id column. I want to add unique constraint it to it. Many of the row's containts NULL or empty for emp_id. if i enter below query, it shows the error.

```
alter table users_userprofile add unique(emp_id);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'emp_id'
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has no problem with multiple `NULL`s regarding adding a unique constraint.  But, as the error message shows, multiple empty strings `''` are not allowed.  As a workaround, you could first update the `emp_id` column to replace empty string with `NULL`:

```
UPDATE users_userprofile
SET emp_id = NULL
WHERE emp_id = '';
```

Then, run your alter statement:

```
ALTER TABLE users_userprofile ADD UNIQUE(emp_id);
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland Well the OP's server mode can't be doing that, otherwise MySQL wouldn't be complaining about multiple `''`, right?

Comment: I got you bro +1.  But, playing the devil's advocate, doing that would make empty string behave this way in _every_ table in the database, and maybe the OP would not want that.

Comment: yes totally agree removing the comments to not futher confuse and preventing people into running unwanted "devil SQL" which can indeed cause bugs/problems when sql_mode is not restored on session before running other queries aswell..